# Полный запрет на изменения константы

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  volatile const int number = 100;

  printf("%i\n", number);

  *const_cast<int*>(&number) = 101;

  printf("%i\n", number);

  *(int*)&number = 102;

  printf("%i\n", number);

  return 0; 
}
```

> output:
>
> 100
>
> 101
>
> 102

Возможно ли добиться того, чтобы трюки не работали?

Comment: `int number() { return 100; }` :)

Comment: использовать макроопределение как констунту времени компиляции

Comment: а они и сейчас не работают, `*const_cast<int*>(&number) = 101;` дает неопределенное поведение

Comment: `enum Int {number = 100};`

Comment: Увольнять тех, кто пишет такой код.